# How to do docker-compose down without the config file that made the up?

Tags: docker, configuration, configuration-management, docker-compose, shutdown

When you do `docker-compose up`, it's based on a `docker-compose.yml` file.

This usually brings up a network, builds and runs multiple services. If you do the up with the `-d` flag, the `docker-compose` client detaches and let the servers alone.

If you do a `docker-compose down`, it shuts down the running containers and in addition removes the corresponding networks.

But... what if after the `up`, the `.yml` file has gone?

### Question

Do you have to manually do the shutdown via `docker stop` finding manually what are the services of that project, and `docker rm` and `docker network rm` and so on?

Or `docker-compose` is intelligent enough to tag all the things (containers, nets, etc.) with a tag so you can tell it some thing like `docker-compose down project-name` so it does not look in the `.yml` (which is now not in the filesystem) file but inspecting the running instances and nets?

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK you cannot just use `docker-compose down` without a corresponding `docker-compose.yml`.

However, your idea with the tagging is not so far from reality either: When invoking `docker-compose up`, `docker-compose` prefixes all the things it creates by the compose file's directory name. This allows identifying sets of containers which belong together even without the corresponding `docker-compose.yml` file. I frequently end up writing variations of this into my interactive shell:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a | grep ... | cut -c -16)
```

Of course, if one were to script that "properly", one would use Docker's ability to format and search its output and rely properly on the names or IDs instead of just the first 16 characters from the IDs. Additionally, this is operation is idempotent because it fails if there are no matches for the `grep`.

Afterwards follow `docker network rm ...` and `docker volume rm ...` to clean up the remainder.